Run pods in parallel in Azure Devops to run a single job
I want to run my azure devops agent pool using kubernetes. I am using this to run a Jupyter notebook which takes quite a bit of time to run. I want to know if it is possible for one job which runs the jupyter notebook to be executed accross multiple pods so that time to run the piepline can be decreased.
I have configure my agent pool as mentioned in Azure DevOps — Self Hosted Agents on Kubernetes — PART-1.
I am able to use hpa to create replicas if the cpu gets high but when the replicas are created they don't get utilized by the pipeline but just sit idle as shown below.

Is it possible so that the job can be spread across the multiple pods or is there another way to run this job in parallel to reduce the time it takes to run the jupyter notebook.


Is it possible so that the job can be spread across the multiple pods

Each build agent can process one and only one job at a time. A job cannot be simultaneous run by multiple build agents.
Considering the above and generally speaking, you should break down your pipeline in multiple pieces that can run in parallel (each piece running in its own pipeline job). If that is not possible, I suggest you do a bit of research in order to understand what other options you have to parallelize your work.
I never used Jupyter notebooks so I'm not able to help you, but I found some links that might be helpful:

Python Simple Loop Parallelization Jupyter Notebook
Parallelising Python code

